# populate Dropdownlist in ui grid dynamically

Tags: angularjs, ui-grid

i have spent lots of hours finding a solution but no success every time i am finding a solution it ends up with static data not from any web API or database. i want dynamic data to be populated  in drop down list in UI grid. i have read in one blog in which guy was saying for dynamic data we have to use *editDropdownRowEntityOptionsArrayPath* but i did not find any useful solution. any one can provide any useful information than i will be vary thankful. thanks in advance. this is what i have done.

```
             $scope.listOptions = []; $scope.ddlist = [];
        $http.get('http://localhost:26413/api/MenuVDN/GetVDNList')
        .then(function (data) { 
            $scope.listOptions = data;
            $scope.ddlist = $scope.listOptions.data.Table;
            console.log($scope.ddlist);
        })
        $scope.gridOptions = {
            enableColumnResizing: true,
            enableSorting: true,
            enableCellSelection: true,
            canSelectRows: true,
        //    enableCellEdit: true,
            columnDefs: [
            { field: 'NameEn', displayName: ' Menu Name', grouping: { groupPriority: 0 }, sort: { priority: 0, direction: 'asc' }, width: '25%' },
            { field: 'id', displayName: 'ID' },
            { field: 'language', displayName: 'VDN Language', grouping: { groupPriority: 1 }, sort: { priority: 1, direction: 'asc' } },
            { field: 'vdnname', displayName: 'VDN Name'  },
            {
                field: 'vdnnum', displayName: 'VDN Number',
                editableCellTemplate: 'ui-grid/dropdownEditor',
               // editDropdownIdLabel: 'id',
                editDropdownValueLabel: 'value',
             //   enableFocusedCellEdit: true,
                enableCellEditOnFocus :true,
                enableCellEdit: true,
                editType: 'dropdown',
                editDropdownRowEntityOptionsArrayPath : $scope.ddlist
  //             ,  cellEditableCondition: function( $scope ) { return true; }
            }
            ]
        };
```

plus i am getting response from webapi in json format like this.

```
{"Table":[{"id":2,"value":"AR-BOOKING-NEW (7101)"},
{"id":3,"value":"EN-BOOKIN-NEW (7102)"},
{"id":4,"value":"AR-BOOKING-CANCEL (7103)"},
{"id":5,"value":"EN-BOOKING-CANCEL (7104)"},
{"id":6,"value":"AR-BOOKING-MODIFY (7105)"}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $scope.columns = completedFiles.columns;
    $scope.rows = completedFiles.rows;
    //prepare custom column for ui-grid
    var customColumns = [];

angular.forEach($scope.columns, function(column) {
            customColumns.push({
                field : column.fieldName,
                displayName : column.displayName,
                editable : column.editable,
                dataType : column.dataType,                   
            });
        }
});

angular.forEach(customColumns, function(customColumn) {
        customColumn['width'] = 200;
        if (customColumn.dataType === 'dropDown') {
            customColumn['cellTemplate'] = "<div class='ui-grid-cell-contents' id='col-description'><select class="form-control" data-ng-options="item in grid.appScope.arrayName track by item" ><option value="" selected hidden />/></select></div>";
            customColumn['width'] = 180;
        }
    });
```

You can create custom template like above and after that just assign in $scope.gridOptions customColumns to columnDefs rather then defining the column definition there.